# val cond: (Int, Int) => Boolean = (...) what does this scala code mean?

Tags: scala

I'm confused about the first line of code.

And what's the difference between the first line and the second line?

```
val cond: (Int, Int) => Boolean = (...)  //confused
val cond = (x: Int, y: Int) => x > y  //anonymous function
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be a bit daunting at first, but all Scala declarations are the same shape:

```
val <name>[: <type>] = <value>
```

If the `type` is not there the compiler will set it to the type of the `value`

So the first case breaks down like this:

- The `name` is `cond`
- The `type` is `(Int, Int) => Boolean`
- The `value` is `(...)`

The second case breaks down like this:

- The `name` is `cond`
- The `value` is `(x: Int, y: Int) => x > y`
- The `type` is inferred to be `(Int, Int) => Boolean`

In both cases `cond` is a function that takes two `Int`s and returns a `Boolean`.

Comment: FWIW, one could be extra explicit and combine the two cases.

Comment: Thanks. And for those who came here from scala-exercises.org - we can redefine the first line as below: 
val cond:(Int,Int)=>Boolean = (x:Int,y:Int)=>x<y